# Uninstall CivicCRM

Tags: wordpress

I downloaded and extracted CivicCRM for Wordpress, and now cannot do anything with it. I would like to uninstall and start again. Advice I find here has not helped... Why can't I find it in the control panel uninstall list? When I click on uninstall.php document I get a pop-up asking what program I want to use to open it. Many thanks. Steve

Answer (score 3):

if you want a clean start, the easiest way is to go into file manager from the control panel and delete all the files. Navigate to .../wp-content/plugin/civicrm and delete all the contents of this directory and then the directory itself.

You should do the same with .../wp-content/upload/civicrm.

I've installed civicrm with its own database so I have deleted that as well, but if you are using the same database as WordPress you can't do that. But if you had a clean install of WordPress you could just unisntall that as well and. In fact just uninstall WordPress is the simplest and cleanest (if the there is nothing else to loose!

Answer (score 1):

I know in Drupal all I can do inside it is turn it off - not uninstall it. When I want to uninstall it from a site, I do so manually - delete the folder where all the CiviCRM files are at, delete the database, delete the folder inside my files folder where all the log files and such are located. I've never used an automated process for it.

Comment: Thanks, Jenni.   All I see is the extracted folder.  If I do a system search for civicrm I get over 9000 hits.  I would like to delete them all!

Comment: There's the extracted folder. You'll want to delete it. Then you'll need to also delete the folder where it keeps the logs and such. I don't know where you store files in WP. In Drupal it's /home/username/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm